# ¿Como verificar si se ingreso un float o un int en una matriz en python?

Tags: python, matriz

El objetivo es verificar si se ingreso un entero en vez de un float, si bien al especificar si "x" es dek tipo "int", lo que busco es detectar si en lugar de entero se ingreso un float, de modo que use "Try" para que el programa no caiga en ese caso, pero el problema está en volver a solicitar que se ingrese el valor entero en la misma posición que se ingreso el float en la matriz, ya que el programa no esta funcionando correctamente para poder ingresar todos los valores, los ciclos for de filas y columnas no se termina de recorrer adecuadamente, y hasta el momento no encontré la solución. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
matriz=[]
x=int
bandera=True
filas=3
columnas=3
for i in range(filas):
    for j in range(columnas):
        while(bandera==True):
            bandera=False
            print("Introduzca valores Enteros para la matriz")
            print("fila:",i)
            print("columna:",j)
            try:
                x=int(input("Valor entero: "))
            except ValueError:
                bandera=True
                print("Se ingreso un valor real, se solicito un entero")
        matriz[i][j]=x
```

¿Está bien declarar de la siguiente forma: x=int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deben de haber muchas maneras de verificar por un entero, pero tú código tiene errores que no tienen que ver con la verificación del entero, uno de los errores que veo es que al inicio defines la matriz como una lista de una dimensión:

```
matriz=[]
```

Pero a la hora de definir llenar la matriz de valores haces referencia a indices multidimensionales:

```
matriz[i][j]=x
```

Esto de dará un error diciendo que el indice está fuera de rango. Una manera sencilla de resolver esto es crear una matriz vacía antes de llenarla de valores de las dimensiones que especificas en las variables de filas y columnas:

```
matriz =  [ [ None for y in range( columnas ) ] 
             for x in range( filas ) ]
```

Y por último para verificar si es entero o float deben de existir muchas maneras pero se me ocurre utilizar el método del tipo de variable `float` que devuelve true si el float es un número entero llamada `is_integer()`, aquí te dejo un ejemplo para que veas como funciona:

```
numero = 1.23

print(numero.is_integer())
# False

numero = 100.0

print(numero.is_integer())
# True
```

Como este método es exclusivo para `float` entonces debes de castear lo que recibes en la entrada para poder utilizarla (en caso de que el usuario digite un `int`), así:

```
float(x).is_integer()
```

Con mis sugerencias el código quedaría algo como así:

```
x = 0
filas=3
columnas=3

matriz =  [ [ None for y in range( columnas ) ] 
             for x in range( filas ) ] 
             
for i in range(filas):
    for j in range(columnas):
        print("Introduzca valores Enteros para la matriz")
        print("fila:",i)
        print("columna:",j)
        bandera=True
        while(bandera):
            x=input("Valor entero: ")
            if((float(x).is_integer())):
                bandera = False
            else:
                print("Error: Por favor ingrese un numero entero")
                
        matriz[i][j] = int(x)
print(matriz)
```

No se si es la manera más eficiente de hacerlo, pero funciona, suerte con tu programación!